# What am I missing on how to change the df.to_csv outfile name for looping through a folder?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a folder of 16 files and instead of doing it manually every quarter (names will change) I want to write a script that reads in space delimited data and outputs comma delimited.  The input files are .out and the output I want are .csv but with some of the name removed for example:
bls_2.out ---> bls.csv

'''

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import csv


directory = r'C:\Projects'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".out"):
        
        df = pd.read_csv(filename,sep="\s+",header=None,skiprows=15)
        df.to_csv(filename + '.csv',sep=",", index=False,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar="",  escapechar=" ",
                  header=["East","North","Elevation","HoleId","aufaf","aucnf","aufacomf","aucncomf","prvf","ocf",
                          "ccf","ssf","Domain_Code"])

    else:
        continue
```

'''

Comment: Please state what happens with this script. It looks like you'll get `bls_2.out.csv` and it will be in the current working directory instead of the directory where the .out files are. Is this true? Are these bugs?

Comment: correct tdelaney, its a bug that I couldn't figure out but below is a good answer that helped me fix this :)  thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have to remove the file extension before writing a new one. This can be done with `os.path.splitext`. Also, to get the .csv in the original directory, you'll have to join those paths.

```
out_file = os.path.join(directory, os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + ".csv")
```